# Is it possible to send array of image through volley

Tags: android

Is is possible to send array of images using volley library in android. 
e.g

`param.put("images", arrayOfImages);`

Please response as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes. You can !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert the images in base64 strings and send that array of strings using

```
param.put("images", arrayOfImages);
```